# Rails Multiple Nested Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

This is my first Rails project and I am attempting to create a form to add Products that can have multiple Property name and value pairs. I have followed several tutorials and looked at several answers here regarding nested forms, but I am stuck on whether the information is actually saving and displaying the information. I was using the Cocoon gem to dynamically create additional property name and value pairs. I've tried using a plain nested form to make sure I have structured the models correctly - that is the code below. I've included relevant code from my project below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**controllers/products_controller.erb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
    gon.products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @properties = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @properties = @product.properties.build
    @product_properties = @properties.product_properties.build
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
    redirect_to products_path,
    notice: 'The product was successfully created.'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :upc, :available_on,
      :properties_attributes => [:property_name,
        :product_properties_attributes => [:value]
        ])
  end
  def get_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  end
end
```

***models/product.rb***

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties
  has_many :product_properties,
           :through => :properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_properties
  attr_accessor :properties_attributes,
                :product_properties_attributes

  validates :name, :upc, :available_on, presence: true
  validates :name, :upc, uniqueness: true
  validates :upc, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  validates :name, length: { maximum: 1024,
    too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }


  validate :check_length

  def check_length
    unless upc.size == 10 or upc.size == 12 or upc.size == 13
      errors.add(:upc, "length must be 10, 12, or 13 characters")
    end
  end

  validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

  def expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    errors.add(:available_on, "must be a future date") if
      !available_on.blank? and available_on < Date.today
  end

end
```

***models/property.rb***

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :product_properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_properties
  attr_accessor :property_name,
                :value,
                 :product_properties_attributes


  validates :property_name, presence: true
  validates :property_name, uniqueness: true
  validates :property_name, length: { maximum: 255,
    too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }
end
```

***models/product_property.rb***

```
class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessor :value

  validates :value, presence: true
  validates :value, length: { maximum: 255,
    too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }

end
```

***views/products/new.html.erb***

```
<h1>New Product</h1>
<%= form_with scope: @product, url: products_path, local: true do |f| %>

<% if @product.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2>
       <%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
       this product from being saved:
     </h2>
     <ul>
       <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>

  <p>
    <strong>Name</strong><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>UPC</strong><br>
    <%= f.text_field :upc %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Available On</strong><br>
    <%= f.date_field :available_on %>
  </p>

  <h3>Properties</h3>
  <div id='properties'>
    <%= f.fields_for (:properties) do |property| %>
      <%= property.fields_for (:product_properties) do |product_property| %>
      <p>
        <strong>Property Name</strong><br>
        <%= property.text_field :property_name %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <strong>Property Value</strong><br>
        <%= product_property.text_field :value %>
      </p>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
  </div>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add Product" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

***views/products/index.html.erb***

```
<h1>Products</h1>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>

<div id="search"></div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>UPC</th>
    <th>Available On</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.name %></td>
      <td><%= product.upc %></td>
      <td><%= product.available_on %></td>
       <% product.properties.each do |property| %>
       <td><%= property.property_name %></td>
       <% end %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Details', product_path(product) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: "but I am stuck on whether the information is actually saving and displaying the information.".........can you elaborate more on this point? Is it saving? You can check by looking at your web server output in development mode. You can also check by using the rails console.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon thank you for bringing up how to check that. I was able to and found that it has not saved any of my nested fields data.

Comment: you can check whether you can see those values in  your params hash, and whether you have permitted those params......you could use byebug for example to help you and the better_errors gem

Comment: Can you show us what is actually posted to the controller? You can find this in the logfile. The params-hash should correspond with your strong parameters specification (the `product_params` method). In any case you are missing the `:id` and `:_destroy` parameters for the nested attributes (needed for cocoon to work correctly). The params posted to the controller will also show how the hash is nested.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I did check the values/params and 1) I had a mistake in the formatting of the params, which I updated to the below params. 2) I am getting an unpermitted parameter :property.                    
 params.require(:product).permit(:name, :upc, :available_on,
     properties_attributes: [:id, :property_name, :_destroy,
        product_properties_attributes: [:id, :value, :_destroy]
        ])

Comment: @nathanvda Yes, here is what I have from the console. I added the :id and :_destroy now. {"authenticity_token"=>"7XlR7jlJReke/meUAqrSlviXWreUk6z+YhU05YPNdg0zO7+wIUz7r2joh6RAIunZI2FbCuWhX11CENTbMmwzlg==", "product"=>{"name"=>"Flannel Shirt", "upc"=>"566749494134", "available_on"=>"2019-11-26", "property"=>{"property_name"=>"Color", "product_property"=>{"value"=>"Blue"}}}, "commit"=>"Add Product"}

Comment: What's the problem, is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `form_with` which combines the previous `form_for` and `form_tag` makes it on the one hand pretty powerful but also sometimes very confusing. What used to be simply `form_for @product`, now you *have* to write

```
form_with model: @product, local: true do |f|
```

Your use of `scope:` just uses `@product` as a prefix and will not actually iterate over or use the `@product` to find associations, that is why we do not see the `property_attributes`, nor the implicit `id` field, even though you correctly have the `accepts_nested_attributes` (the `_destroy` field would be added by cocoon's `link_to_remove_association` --if you would want to go back to the ability to dynamically add/remove nested items).

Comment: That worked and I was able to add back the dynamically added fields. Thank you!!